# Which Angular router should I use?

Tags: angularjs

I'm starting an Angular project today, expected to go live in 1-2 months. I'm currently using the latest 1.4 version, but would be open to use 1.5 instead.

I'm trying to get my head around the best choice of router for the application: ngRoute, ui-router or ngNewRouter. Best being defined by available documentation, stability of implementation, how future-proof it is (with upcoming Angular 2 release) and functionality.

(Not entirely sure why this question is voted down as I believe it's a valid concern when starting development of a new Angular project. I'm not trying to start a religious debate about routers, but would like to use solid arguments to make a decision that I will not regret in a few months. Especially with 1.5 and 2.0 are around the corner this is not an obvious decision...)

Comment: too many open ended factors to take into account to answer that properly.  if you need it live in 1 - 2 months, which is very soon, pick the one you know.

Comment: Well, I taught myself ngRoute yesterday so not sure if the counts as knowing ;-)

Comment: ngRoute and ngNewRouter are both maintained by the angular team, the main difference being that ngNewRouter is usable in Angular 2.  ui-router is a 3rd party module which is a state machine.  Which one is right for your purpose, however, isn't something we can answer.  It's likely that the question is drawing down votes for being subjective and not having a question that has a definitive, proven singular correct answer possible.

Comment: also, despite angular 2 being in alpha for over a year, with no evidence to back the claim, people have been making the same "upcoming Angular 2 release" statement for *months*.  Unless you have evidence of an announced date for Angular 2 being moved from alpha status, you probably shouldn't pose questions based on unfounded rumor.  Angular 2 could be completely incompatible with everything you try to do now, no matter how hard you try to prepare for it.

Comment: I guess the only huge argument for ngRoute is its size. It offers basic routing features for a fraction of the size of UI.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I have decided to go ahead with ngRoute and migrate to the new router once officially available. ui-router looks great but I prefer to keep the number of external components to a minimum.

Answer (score 3):

I'd definitely choose ui-router. It's extremely powerful, scalable, and easy to use. It's supported by core angular team and will be fully supported in 2.0, see Routing @ http://angularjs.blogspot.cz/